# Holomorphic extension of a function to $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am stuck at the following question :

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n) | z_1=z_2=0\}$. Show that $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

I think that I have to somehow use the Riemann extension theorem here. But I am not being able to carry out the details.

Can anybody please help ?? Any suggestion or comment is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hartog's theorem.  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243572/proof-of-hartogss-theorem/243614#243614) for a standard proof.

Comment: @WimC: no,  Hartogs's theorem does not answer the question if $n\gt 2$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I see what you mean and you're right.  Easy to fix since by Hartog it extends in the first two variables.  The referenced proof works unaltered.  (Other formulations of Hartog's theorem do cover this case, for example omitting a product of fewer discs (but at least two) or a compact set with connected complement.)

Answer (score 3):

Riemann's second extension theorem says that if $M$ is a holomorphic manifold and  $S\subset M$ is an analytic subset **of codimension at least two**, the restriction map $\mathcal O(M) \to \mathcal O(M\setminus S) $ is bijective.
Your question is solved by applying this result to $M=\mathbb C^n$ and $S=\{(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n) \in \mathbb C^n| z_1=z_2=0\}$

The theorem is not very difficult but for some reason it is underappreciated and rather difficult to find in the literature.
I located a slightly weaker but very elementary version  in Gunning's  [Introduction to Holomorphic Functions of Several Variables, volume I](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Introduction_to_Holomorphic_Functions_of.html?id=8UBYQz3Ro9cC&redir_esc=y), Theorem 2, page 30.
(The weaker version is local and supposes $S$ smooth, but this suffices for your question).
The general version can be found in Grauert-Remmert's masterful [Coherent analytic Sheaves](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Coherent_Analytic_Sheaves.html?id=HyCFQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), page 132.